# How to set background image for text into UIlabel?

Tags: iphone, image, text, uilabel

We can set color to text in UILabel. But can we set image to text in UILabel? Can you help me? Thanks all!

Comment: looke like: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/s7iau

Comment: I have imageview contain text...I'm trying set image background into text, not background of imageView...??

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel *lbl  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 220, 200, 30)];

[lbl setText:@"Hello"];

[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

if you need to set image for your UILabel, you can try like this:

[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]]];

[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

**If you want your textColor as Image then please do this**

```
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_select.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UILabel` is only for text. If you want an image, use an `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the image you linked to using a `UILabel`, you can do that by setting the label's text and `backgroundColor. Then you use`UIColor colorWithPatternImage:`for the orange color pattern. Then use that color for the label's`textColor`.