# Iphone Set background image into text in uitextView?/

Tags: iphone, image, background, addition

I have a `uiimageView` containing the text like [this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/9fsj8).

I want to set the image background of the text to look like [this instead](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/qthaj).

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13736765/1443976

Answer (score 1):

You will need to combine an image of the text with the background image (the stuff that is supposed to fill the inside of the text) using *compositing*. Take a look at the various blend modes you can use, or look into the use of CIFilter.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

The thing in the background looks like it might be a gradient. Again, you can use a CIFilter to generate that gradient, or you can use Core Graphics. So you'll composite the drawn text with its fill image, then you'll draw that over a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

instead of text in black solid color, make image with transparent text and outer region as the grey gradient you want and put this image over you background image, you will get the desired result.